# IBM Worklight - How to connect to SQL server

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a SQL server with 1 database and i want to connect to it from my Worklight app and get data.

How can I do that? I've tried with HTTP adapter but where to put userid and password to access the sql server?

Comment: if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP adapters are not meant for connecting to a SQL backend server... for that purpose you should use **SQL** adapters. [There is a training module for it](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf). There is also a [sample application](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/SQLAdapter.zip). Please don't go straight to the sample - read the training module first.

You will find out that you need to place the database username and password as well as the URL to it, in the adapter's XML file, like the following.

Note that there are more configurations to do before this will work:

- Create a database, its table(s) and set its user permissions
- Place the SQL Connector driver (in Eclipse >> Worklight project\server\lib folder)

Make sure to read the training module, where this is all explained.

```
<dataSourceDefinition>
    <driverClass>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
    <user>myUsername</user>
    <password>myPassword</password> 
</dataSourceDefinition>
```

To better understand Worklight, [study the IBM-provided training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).